# C# Cursor control on 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: c#, mouse-cursor

I'm looking for a C# class to control mouse movements on a 64 bit Windows machine. Does anyone have a link to one?

Here's one exactly like I need but it only works for x86:
http://thecodeisart.blogspot.com/2008/11/mouse-control.html

Comment: that should work on 64 bit. Anyway 64 bit OS runs 32 bit apps quite happily.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the build type on your project explicitly to x86 you should be good to go.

[image]

If it's currently 'Any CPU' that will freak-out poorly written interop.